# htaccess mobile redirect is redirecting on PC

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have my main site (www.jguffphotography.com) currently redirected with htaccess to (mobile.jguffphotography).  THAT works fine

I have a directory separately redirected (www.jguffphotography.com/photopage/) to (mobile.jguffphotography.com/photopage)

I have an htaccess file on my main domain, and in the photopage directory.

All is working great from my phone, but on a PC the photopage URLS are redirecting to the mobile sub domain.

---

The main domain htaccess coding I have is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mobile.jguffphotography.com [L,R=302]
```

the one I have in the photopage directory is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/photopage/([^.]+).html$ http://mobile.jguffphotography.com/photopage/$1.html
```

Comment: Maybe there is an easier route where I can redirect everything on my site to the subdomain? (I'd still need the $1 to decipher all the different urls)

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectCond` is part of mod_rewrite and applies to a following `RewriteRule`. `RedirectMatch` is part of mod_alias and doesn't have anything to do with the previous condition. You need to stick with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^photopage/([^.]+).html$ http://mobile.jguffphotography.com/photopage/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That fixed the PC redirecting to the mobile subdomain, but now on a phone, the photopage won't redirect at all